# I try to make a user in firebase, and it works in all the browsers except of Safari

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, safari, firebase-authentication

My code dosent work in Safari (it works in Firefox, Google Chrome). I try to make a user in firebase with the btn.onclick function in javascript, it works in all the browsers except of safari. I have three inputs a name, an email, and a password and I make a user in firebase with createUserWithEmailAndPassword, but if Im on the website in safari nothing happens, and there is no user created in firebase auth.
Here is my HTML and JS:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Mysite</title>

    
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail" id="email" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="password" id="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="submitBtn" />

    <!-- Insert these scripts at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->
  
    <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.19.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  
    <!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.19.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  
    <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.19.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.19.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>


    <script>
       var firebaseConfig = {
       apiKey: "apiKey",
       authDomain: "authDomain",
       databaseURL: "databaseURL",
       projectId: "projectId",
       storageBucket: "storageBucket",
       messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId",
       appId: "appId"
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

      var uname = document.getElementById("name").value;
      var uemail = document.getElementById("email").value;
      var upassword = document.getElementById("password").value;
      const subBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
```

And after that I make the user with createUserWithEmailAndPassword.
I tried to add the onclick function to the html, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: No, there are none.